# Getting a NullpointerException on Samsung Galaxy S21+ Only for nativeGetStyleAttribute

Tags: android, view, attr

The NullPointerException is getting for all the devices running Android 10 and above, only if "View Attribute Inspection" option enabled from Developer Options. But specifically for Samsung Galaxy S21+ is getting this issue even the "View Attribute Inspection" option is disabled.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.content.res.XmlBlock.nativeGetStyleAttribute(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.XmlBlock.access$1500(XmlBlock.java:41)
    at android.content.res.XmlBlock$Parser.getStyleAttribute(XmlBlock.java:459)
    at android.content.res.Resources$Theme.getExplicitStyle(Resources.java:1937)
    at android.view.View.retrieveExplicitStyle(View.java:7009)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5893)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:255)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.<init>(RelativeLayout.java:251)
```

Answer (score 1):

I first saw this issue after attaching the layout inspector in Android Studio. But after I stopped using the layout inspector the issue persisted.

**I had to factory reset my device to get rid of this issue.** Exact same code - but a factory reset fixed the problem. It's like the device got stuck with View Attribute Inspection turned on even though I turned it off in settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was enough to turn off `Enable view attribute inspection` in device preferences/Developer options.
The crazy part is that my app was crashing on this device even when I downloaded already published version from the PlayStore.